# how to update buildversion.txt file after build using ant and jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins

I execute an ant xml file using jenkins. I have to update the versionbuild.txt file information before making war.
my ant tasks are init, clean, prepare, compile, war
before making war, I want to access some parameters like date_of_build, build_number, jdk_compiler, compiler_platform, build_person. Update these in text file named versionbuild.txt file and archive into war.

Comment: What is versionbuild.txt? Is this related to jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar in one of my build scripts. Basically creating a properties file which I place as a resource in the source folder. Here's the snippet:

```
<target name="init">
  <!-- Format the build number to a 4 figures integer with leading zeroes if required -->
  <!-- The build number is also incremented by 1                                      -->
  <propertyfile file="${build.number.file}">
    <entry key="build.number" type="int" default="0000" operation="+" pattern="0000" />
  </propertyfile>
  <!-- Read the build number -->
  <property file="${build.number.file}"/>
  <!-- create the build date and time with time zone -->
  <tstamp>
    <format property="readable.now" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm z"/>
  </tstamp>
  <!-- Write thebuild and version information to a resource file -->
  <!-- The resource file will be part of the corresponding jar   -->
  <propertyfile file="${node}/src/resources/META-INF/jppf-version.properties">
    <entry key="version.number" type="string" value="${version.number}"/>
    <entry key="build.number" type="string" value="${build.number}"/>
    <entry key="build.date" type="string" value="${readable.now}"/>
  </propertyfile>
</target>
```

The resulting file looks like this:

```
#Wed, 30 Apr 2014 07:45:12 +0200
version.number=4.2 alpha
build.number=1352
build.date=2014-04-30 07\:45 CEST
```

Obviously, some of the data you need is not in there, but you can easily add them as `<entry>` elements, using the name of the corresponding [system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) as the value, for instance:

```
<propertyfile file="${path.to}/versionbuild.txt">
  <entry key="build_number" type="string" value="${build.number}"/>
  <entry key="date_of_build" type="string" value="${readable.now}"/>
  <entry key="jdk_compiler" type="string" value="${java.vm.version}"/>
  <entry key="jdk_compiler" type="string" value="${os.name}"/>
  <entry key="build_person" type="string" value="${user.name}"/>
</propertyfile>
```